# Array search/compare is slow, compare to Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I just switched from VBA (Excel) to VB (Visual Studio Express 2013).
Now I have copied parts of my code from VBA to VB.
And now I'm wondering why VB is so slow... 
I'm creating an Array (IFS_BV_Assy) with 4 column and about 4000 rows.
There are some identical entrys in it, so I compare every entry with each other and override the duplicate with a empty string.
The Code looks like that:

```
    For i = 1 To counter
        For y = 1 To counter
            If IFS_BV_Assy(1, y) = IFS_BV_Assy(1, i) And i <> y Then
                If IFS_BV_Assy(2, i) < IFS_BV_Assy(2, y) Then
                    IFS_BV_Assy(1, i) = ""
                Else
                    IFS_BV_Assy(1, y) = ""
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Counter is the lenght of the Array.

In VBA it takes about 1 Sec. In VB it takes about 30 Sec. to go thru the loop. Somebody knows why? (im creating some Timestamp between every Step to be sure whats slow. And that loop is the bad guy)

The Array looks like this:

- (1,1) = 12.3.015 / (2,1) = 02
- (1,2) = 12.3.016 / (2,2) = 01   <-- delete
- (1,3) = 12.3.016 / (2,3) = 02   <-- keep, because 02 is newer then 01
- (1,4) = 12.3.017 / (2,4) = 01
- (1,5) = 12.3.018 / (2,5) = 01

Thanks in advance

Andy

Edit: I create the Array like that:

```
    strStartPath_BV_Assy = "\\xxx\xx\xx\"
    myFile = Dir(strStartPath_BV_Assy & "*.*")
    counter = 1
    ReDim IFS_BV_Assy(0 To 2, 0 To 0)
    IFS_BV_Assy(0, 0) = "Pfad"
    IFS_BV_Assy(1, 0) = "Zg."
    IFS_BV_Assy(2, 0) = "Rev"

    Do While myFile <> ""
        If UCase(Right(myFile, 3)) = "DWG" Or UCase(Right(myFile, 3)) = "PDF" Then
            ReDim Preserve IFS_BV_Assy(0 To 2, 0 To counter)
            IFS_BV_Assy(0, counter) = strStartPath_BV_Assy + myFile
            IFS_BV_Assy(1, counter) = Left(Mid(myFile, 12), InStr(1, Mid(myFile, 12), "-") - 1)
            IFS_BV_Assy(2, counter) = Mid(myFile, Len(myFile) - 8, 2)
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
        myFile = Dir()
    Loop
```

Comment: How are you defining the array? Are the values boxed?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: I edit my question to add the code for creating the array. Thanks for the Link. Is this also for VB?

Comment: Like what?  `Dim IFS_BV_Assy(,,,) as String` or just `Dim IFS_BV_Assy(,,,)`. If the items are of Object type, then each is unboxed for comparison which will give you a big performance hit.

Comment: Yes, it is also for VB .NET.

Comment: Sorry, I can't put the Code here, so I edit the question. Your right, I create the Array `as String`. And now its about 3.9 - 4.5 Sec. in compare of 1 - 2 Sec. for VBA. Thanks for that Stokke

Answer (score 0):

Maybe data was best case (around 4000) when ran in VBA.
30 sec seems a reasonable time for 4000x4000=16.000.000 iterations. 1 sec is too low for this number of iterations.

Comment: Yes, I know there is a huge No. of rows. But it's the same code in both Programms... So, in fact; VBA is that fast.

Comment: VBA uses the same code base of VB. VBA can be slower or equal to VB but not faster.

Answer (score 0):

Stokke suggested to create the array `as String` instead of Objekt Type.

```
Dim IFS_BV_Assy(,) as String
```

I create the Module with `Option Explicit Off`, because I never see any difference in VBA for that point. Now I declare any variable with `Dim .. as ...`.
And now, it's as fast as VBA is =)

Learning = making mistakes.. =)